# Total time for Network-Calls during a page load in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to know how much time took for completing All network(HTTP) calls to load a Main Component-page.

**Ex:** In main-page, i have 3 child components(Child 1-3) which has it's own HTTP calls(Synchronous / Asynchronous / Both).

[image]

let's **assume** network call sequence is below:

1. child-1's HTTP-call1
2. child-2's HTTP-call1
3. child-1's HTTP-call2
4. child-1's HTTP-call3
5. child-3's HTTP-call1
6. child-3's HTTP-call2

i want to know time taken for executing all these 6-Network calls.

*Requirement:* I need to calculate every time i refresh/load page get total n/w time and store for analytic purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome developer tools have a Network tab - every HTTP request could be tracked there.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: for once, i can use this. But I need to calculate every time when i refresh/load page get time and store for analytic purpose

Comment: you have updated requirements and the question - it can be viewed in history. If my answer suits your initial question - please, accept it and close the question. For your analytics specific question - open a new one :)

Comment: for a question, it's not mandatory to view all from a single perspective, can't close and raise a new ticket for a small update. I mentioned query comes under which Category/Tag and expecting an Answer from the same Category not using any tool.